# Solve motion from Hamilton's equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have a system of four coordinates and four momenta (conjugates of coordinates).

I have a metric tensor $g_{ik}$ and I know the Hamiltonian:

$H(p,q,t)=\frac{1}{2}g^{ik}(q)p_ip_k$

For my current case I have the Schwartzschild metric:

$ds^2=(1-r_s/r)dt^2-\frac{1}{1-r_s/r}dr^2-r^2d\theta^2-r^2sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2$

Meaning, the Hamiltonian is:

$H=\frac{1}{2}[\frac{1}{1-r_s/r}p_t^2-(1-r_s/r)p_r^2-\frac{1}{r^2}p_\theta^2-\frac{1}{r^2sin^2(\theta)}p_\phi^2]$

As *Mathematica* code with $r_s = 1$,

```
h =  1/2 (1/(1 - 1/r) pt^2 - (1 - 1/r) pr^2 - 1/r^2 pθ^2 - 1/(r^2 Sin[θ]^2) pϕ)
```

The equations of motion by Hamilton's equations are:

$dt/d\tau=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_t};$

$dr/d\tau=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_r};$

$d\theta/d\tau=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_\theta};$

$d\phi/d\tau=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_\phi};$

$dp_t/d\tau=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial t};$

$dp_r/d\tau=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial r};$

$dp_\theta/d\tau=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial \theta};$

$dp_\phi/d\tau=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial \phi};$

And I want to solve these equations of motion. I've tried deriving the expressions for each partial derivatives of $H$ and then substituting them in these equations manually. However, is there any way to do this dynamically?

What I mean is: suppose, we've only got the expression of Hamiltonian:

$H=H(p_t,p_r,p_\theta,p_\phi,t,r,\theta,\phi)$

And I want to dynamically derive all the partial derivatives and construct system of 8 (in this case) first-order differential equations and then solve them with `NDSolve[]`. So, that next time, when I want to try something else, all I have to change is the Hamiltonian.

P.s.: I've tried lots of things, like using `Function[]` for Hamiltonian and throwing variables back and forth, but with no effective result.

Comment: Did you look at `NDSolve`? (Or maybe `DSolve`?)  If it's a separable Hamiltonian system (I didn't check), there are special integration methods available.  See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveSplitting.html.

Comment: I don't think it's separable (at least, at first sight, it's not... there are $r$ s everywhere).
Yes, I've been fighting with `NDSolve[]` this whole time. My problem is, I can't differentiate $H$ partially so that it's analytic. `Mathematica` can't seem to understand that the variables of result functions (partial derivatives) are by themselves functions of $\tau$ and I don't know how to make it understand.

Comment: I've posted an answer based on a function that I wrote earlier. To get a more specific answer regarding your exact problem with differentiation, it would be necessary for you to post the actual *Mathematica* code you've tried.

Comment: After all my attempts failed, I erased them all and substituted the partial derivatives manually. Now I regret that, though...

Comment: My codes, however, were not half as complex as yours is. I'll have to study it carefully. Thanks for sharing, I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a convenience function that I use to solve for the motion under arbitrary classical Hamiltonians:

```
hamiltonSolve[hamilton_, varList_] := Module[
  {inputVariables, initialValues, phaseSpace, t, tMax, localH},
  {t, tMax} = Last[varList];
  {inputVariables, initialValues} = Transpose[Most[varList]];
  phaseSpace = Through[inputVariables[t]];
  localH = hamilton /. Thread[inputVariables -> phaseSpace];
  inputVariables /. First[
    NDSolve[
     Join[Thread[
       D[phaseSpace, t] == Flatten[
         Reverse[{-1, 1}*Partition[
            D[localH, {phaseSpace}], Length[phaseSpace]/2
            ]]
         ]],
      Thread[(phaseSpace /. t -> 0) == initialValues
       ]],
     inputVariables,
     {t, 0, tMax},
     MaxSteps -> Infinity]
    ]
  ]

sol = hamiltonSolve[
  1/2 (1/(1 - 1/r) pt^2 - (1 - 1/r) pr^2 - 1/r^2 pθ^2 - 1/(r^2 Sin[θ]^2) pϕ), 
   {{t1, 0.1}, {r, 2}, {θ, 0.1}, {ϕ, 0}, 
    {pt, 1}, {pr, .1}, {pθ, 0}, {pϕ, .1}, {t, 10}}];
```

This provides all solutions as [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) objects which can be plotted. For example, here is the time as a function of proper time (I copied your Hamiltonian and set $r_s=1$):

```
Plot[sol[[1]][t],{t,0,10}]
```

[image: plot of time]

The Hamiltonian is provided as the first argument of `hamiltonSolve`, and the second argument is a list of all the canonical variables with their initial values. As its last argument, the list additionally contains the name of the proper time variable (here I just call it `t` because it doesn't appear in the Hamiltonian anyway), together with the desired duration of the integration. The list of canonical variables must be *even*, and it is assumed that the canonical momenta are listed as the *second half* of the list (excluding the proper time).

So the list `varList` is generally of the form

> `{{x, x0}, {y, y0}, ... , {px, px0}, {py, py0}, ...,  {t, tMax}}.`

where in your case I entered the time `t1` as the first coordinate, so that the corresponding momentum `pt` is the fifth entry in the list above.

Comment: I wanted to use your `Code` for my problem but very hard to understand how you construct `hamiltonSolve[...]`. My Hamilton function is: `-0.2 II[t] m1[t] (1 - 0.18 n0[t])^2 SS[t] + 
 m2[t] (-0.02 II[t] + 0.2 II[t] (1 - 0.18 n0[t])^2 SS[t]) + 
 0.97 (-0.65 II[t] - SS[t] + n0[t] (II[t] + SS[t]))^2` and co-state vars are `m1[t], m2[t]` and my state variables are `SS[t], II[t]` and control variable is `n0[t]`. Initial values: `SS[0]=.97, II[0]=.02, m1[0]=2, m2[0]=10`. Can you run your function using these parameters? Also, I do not understand why you have `{t1, .1}` in your function.