# How to compute symbolically the Legendre transform of a function?

Tags: functional

Is it possible to compute symbolically the [Legendre transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) of a function in Mathematica?

I find no `LegendreTransform` function.

Comment: See:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151512/legendre-transform-of-a-function-of-a-3-vector/151536#151536

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I had missed your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote a small function to compute Legendre transform of differentiable univariate functions.

```
LegendreTransform[f_]:=Module[{x,y,sol,expr},
    sol = Solve[f'[x] == y, x, Reals];
    expr = FullSimplify[First[y x - f[x]/.sol], {x,y}\[Element]Reals];
    Evaluate[expr/.y->#]&]
```

Some examples:

```
LegendreTransform[-Log[#] &]
(* -1 + Log[-(1/#1)] & *)

LegendreTransform[Exp[#] &]
(* ConditionalExpression[(-1 + Log[#1]) #1, #1 > 0] & *)
```

Comment: It works only when $f$ is convex